# How to login to twitter via Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter

Sorry if this question has been asked before, I've look for a while and haven't found anything related. I recently started delving into AJAX/Javascript and for fun I was curious if it was possible to log into Twitter via an AJAX call.

So I looked at the [source code](https://twitter.com/) for the login page, and it looks like on line 198 and 202 (Chrome source code viewer) the username and password keys are set, respectively, as well as the page it's being sent to. So from there I wrote this:

```
$.post('https://twitter.com/sessions', 
    {"session[username_or_email]" : "USERNAME",
    "session[password]": "PASSWORD"},
    function(data) {
        $('body').html(data);
});
```

It returns something along the lines of "Username/Password" are incorrect. Are the fields wrong? Is my approach fundamentally flawed? If so, how could a similar effect be achieved? Thanks!

Edit: Follow up question, if I send an ajax request and that page should create/set a cookie, what happens to that cookie? Does it just evaporate, or is it set for the browser?

Comment: There's an [API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth) for that ?

Comment: @adeneo Yep, as I said it's more of a proof-of-concept/fun project to learn about the tech.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you're trying to accomplish once connected to twitter. [Searching](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets) for tweets for example, does not require you to login.

Comment: @Graham eventually I was going to try to see if I could send tweets from my program, but I just assumed the first step was to login.